# linux-image-6.2.0-26-genetic kernel ubuntu 22.04 installation error

Tags: system-installation, 22.04

```
Error installing linux-image-6.20-26-generic
installed linuximage-6.2.0-26-generic package post-installation script
subprocess returned error exit status 1.
```

The installation is 6.20-26-generic but they are up to 6.20-32-generic now for 22.04.3. I don't know how to fix it.

```
E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)  
The following packages are in a broken state: 
This may be due to using an old installer image, 
or it may be due to a bug in some of the packages listed above. 
More details may be found in /var/log/syslog. 
The installer will try to continue anyway but may fail at a later point  
and will not be able to install or remove other packages 
(possibly including itself) from the installed system.
```

The version I installed is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS downloaded from official website. I've tried reinstalling Ubuntu, but the same error occurred.

[image]

Comment: Error while installing packages:
An error occurred while installing packages.
E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The following packages are in a broken state:
This may be due to using an old installer image, or it maybe due to a budin some of the packages listed above. More details may be found in /var/log/syslog. The installer will try to continue anyway but may fail at a later point and will not be able to install or remove other packages (possiblyincluding itself) from the installed svstem.

Comment: Why are you trying to install `6.20-26-generic` when they are up to `6.20-32-generic` now for 22.04.3?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1485380/edit) your question with updates, and don't use the comments down here.  Thank you and welcome to AskUbuntu!